# What is a suitable/recommended cable for OpenTherm?

Tags: opentherm

I have the Nest HeatLink connected to the boiler via OpenTherm. I need to move the HeatLink due to wireless connection problems with the thermostat.

The Wikipedia page for OpenTherm states that I can use a cable up to 50m with 2x5 ohm resistance. Not sure how to translate that into a specific decision for a type of cable.

Does anyone have more information on what would be a good cable for this application?

Comment: I got this from the protocol specification:

Number of Wires : 2
Wiring type : untwisted pair *
Maximum line length : 50 metres
Maximum cable resistance : 2 * 5 Ohms
Polarity of connections : Polarity-free, i.e. interchangeable.
* In electrically noisy environments it may be necessary to use twisted pair or screened cable.

Comment: Where are you on this planet? Do your local wiring standards enforce requirements on low voltage control wiring?

Comment: @DDS -- that's an answer.  Post it as such and I'll give you a +1 for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use standard 1 pair of 0,6 mm^2 'phone' (class3) cable, it'll be enough (70 ohm/km, you'll get 5 ohm with 70m so well over the 50m OT limit) and also suitable for noisy environments as it's twisted. Remember to check that cable insulation is rated at least 250V if you run it in same mains power conduits as required by CEI regulations